# EXCEL - Average if cells in a column contain any of the strings in a list (list specific to each row)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average, array-formulas

I would like to get a formula to calculate an "averageif" based on whether the text of a column ("Item" in the example), is included in a string that I have in another column ("Other items" in the example).

So for example for Item A, I would like to get the average of item B and C in column "Output".

Is there an easy way to do this? I thought about array-SEARCH but keep getting errors

[image: Example. Output column is the average of values whose "item" text is included in "Other items"]

Comment: How does your current solution look like? Please show your effort. How many different items can show up in one cell of **Other items**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be `SEARCH` within `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2:$A$5,"," & C2 & ","))*$B$2:$B$5)/SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2:$A$5,"," & C2 & ",")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One can use FILTERXML:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(C2,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")))/SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A:A,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(C2,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")))
```

[image]